# submitting cloud ml engine job for py_binary built with bazel

Tags: bazel, google-cloud-ml

Are there any best practices for deploying CloudML Engine jobs when using bazel?

Let's say I have /src/project/pipeline/trainer, which contains my Tensorflow trainer application. Since I'm using bazel, my imports are relative to the workspace root. I basically need to tar my .runfiles directory and upload it, but pkg_tar with include_runfiles set does not work (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4383), and pkg_runfiles rule is not open source.

I can think of a few ways to do this, but they're all pretty hacky.

Comment: I pinged the bug (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4383), referencing your question.